# pythonのrange関数について

Tags: python

```
# coding: utf-8

import Image as img
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = np.array(img.open("a.png"))

width  = img.shape[0]
height = img.shape[1]

for i in range(height + 1) :
    for j in range(width + 1) :
        img[i][j] = img[i][width] - img[i][j]

plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

python初心者なのですが画像を左右反転させるコードを書いたのですが,

img[i][j] = img[i][width] - img[i][j]
IndexError: index 512 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 512

というエラーが出てしまいます. 
ちなみに, 画像はカラー画像で width = height = 512　です.
エラーが言っていることは何となく分かるのですが, どう修正すれば良いのでしょうか?

Comment: `range(height + 1)` を`range(height)`,  `range(width + 1)`を`range(width)`, `img[i][width]` は おそらく間違い(反転の処理ではないと思われる)。 要点は、５１２ピクセルの時、インデックスは０～５１１だということです。

Comment: 確かに反転はできませんでした.
ただ, 画像を表示させることは出来ました. 
ありがとうございます.

Comment: `transpose(Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)` を使えばいいと思いますが。

Answer (score 1):

`height`「高さ」と`width`「幅」を逆に初期値を与えたと思います。以下を試してください。

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = np.array(img.open("a.png"))
plt.imshow(img)
height  = img.shape[0]
width = img.shape[1]

for i in range(height):
    for j in range(width):
        img[i][:] = img[i][::-1]

plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

一般的にアレイ`a` を[逆の順序](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html#indexing-slicing-and-iterating)にしたい時は`a[ : :-1]`が早いと思います。